# Ubuntu Server cannot ping gateway or resolve names

Tags: networking, server, dns, gateway

I'm dealing with a very strange networking issue.

I'm running Ubuntu Server 22.04 and every client can get to it and the internet on my home network. However, the server cannot even ping the gateway (or anything by name or number, other than itself)! This all seemed to happen after I installed dnsmasq on the server (I have since uninstalled it). I rebooted after removing dnsmasq.

I'm using a static IP on the server and all routes and network config look fine. The IP hasn't changed.

Also, and I don't know if it's related, the server cannot resolve any DNS names. So as a consequence, I cannot apt update, etc.

I didn't change any config other than installing, then removing dnsmasq.

Any help is appreciated.

Many thanks.

UPDATE
2023.11.29

```bash
root@m93p:/etc/netplan# cat 00-installer-config.yaml 
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.2.93/24
      nameservers:
        search: [home]
        addresses: [192.168.2.1, 207.164.234.193]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.2.1
root@m93p:/etc/netplan# netplan generate
root@m93p:/etc/netplan# netplan apply
root@m93p:/etc/netplan#
```

Comment: Modern Ubuntu uses `systemd-dnsmasq`. You may have trashed the configuration. Start with `man systemd-dnsmasq`.

Comment: "I'm using a static IP on the server and all routes and network config look fine." Let's have a look at: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks!  ```root@m93p:/etc/netplan# cat 00-installer-config.yaml 
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'  
network:  
  ethernet:   
    eno1:  
      addresses:  
      - 192.168.2.93/24  
      nameservers:  
        addresses:  
        - 192.168.2.1  
        search:  
        - bowieland.lan  
      routes:  
      - to: default  
        via: 192.168.2.1  
  version: 2  
root@m93p:/etc/netplan#```

Comment: Apologies @chili555 for my terrible markdown skills!

Comment: UPDATE: I can ping other nodes on the subnet, but not the gateway. So weird.

Comment: Please check: `cat /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples/static.yaml` Your file differs. Please note that netplan is very specific about indentation and spacing. Please amend. Follow with: `sudo netplan generate` and: `sudo netplan apply` Post any errors.

Comment: Many thanks @chili555 `root@m93p:/etc/netplan# cat 00-installer-config.yaml 
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.2.93/24
      nameservers:
        search: [bowieland.lan]
        addresses: [192.168.2.1]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.2.1
root@m93p:/etc/netplan# netplan generate 
root@m93p:/etc/netplan# netplan apply
WARNING:root:Cannot call Open vSwitch: ovsdb-server.service is not running.`

Comment: Your netplan file is still not as outlined in the template: `renderer: networkd` Also, see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netplan.io/+bug/1995598 Is this running some kind of container or virtual machine or...? After fixing your netplan file, is there any improvement?

Comment: I get the same vSwithch warning after fixing, generating and applying my netplan file. I'm trying to figure out how to install ovsdb-server from .deb files. I am running docker and snaps on that machine. Thanks for your tenacity @chili555 !

Comment: I installed the vSwitch components via deb files and that got rid of the warning from netplan apply. However, I still can't ping my gateway or resolve names.

Comment: FYI When I give the machine a temporary alternative IP via `sudo ifconfig eno1 192.168.2.99 netmask 255.255.255.0` I can ping the gateway! However, I still can't get past the gateway. A `ping 8.8.8.8` or `ping google.com` still fails.

Comment: run ping -t 1 8.8.8.8 then ping -t 2 8.8.8.8 and ping -t 3 8.8.8.8.  If the first one replies from the router IP address Time to live exceeded, then your config on the Ubuntu box is correct.  If the second hop doesnt reply with an external IP, Time to live exceeded, then the issue is with your router.  That will half your problem, and allow you to focus, on the device causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS with the same result. Then I tried a live Fedora desktop using DHCP and it worked. Then I installed Fedora Server with the .93 static IP and had the same networking issue. So it's not OS related. My router is ISP supplied and has limited capabilities, I couldn't find anything on there that would block a specific static IP. I reinstalled Ubuntu Server 22.04 and used a static IP of .94 and everything works fine, so I have a work around. Many thanks AskUbuntuers for all your help! If I ever figure it out I'll update this post.